# Parsing XML response of bit.ly

Tags: python, xml, parsing, bit.ly

I was trying out the bit.ly api for shorterning and got it to work. It returns to my script an xml document. I wanted to extract out the tag  but cant seem to parse it properly.

```
askfor = urllib2.Request(full_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(askfor)
the_page = response.read()
```

So the_page contains the xml document. I tried:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
doc = parse(the_page)
```

this causes an error. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

parse() thinks the_page is a file. How do i get it to read from the varaibale the_page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide an error message so I can't be sure this is the only error.  But, `xml.minidom.parse` does not take a string.  From the docstring for `parse`:

> Parse a file into a DOM by filename or file object.

You should try:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(askfor)
doc = parse(response)
```

since `response` will behave like a file object.  Or you could use the `parseString` method in `minidom` instead (and then pass `the_page` as the argument).

EDIT: to extract the URL, you'll need to do:

```
url_nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName('url')
url = url_nodes[0]
print url.childNodes[0].data
```

The result of `getElementsByTagName` is a list of all nodes matching (just one in this case).  `url` is an Element as you noticed, which contains a child Text node, which contains the data you need.

Comment: That does parse the_page but i cant seem to get an individual tags. using doc.getElementsByTagName("url") returns: [<DOM Element: url at 0x13cbf80>] instead of the data in between.

Comment: Updated my answer, see above.

Answer (score 1):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
doc = parseString(the_page)
```

See the documentation for [`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

Comment: That does parse the_page but i cant seem to get an individual tags.

using doc..getElementsByTagName("url") 

returns: [<DOM Element: url at 0x13cbf80>] instead of the data.

Comment: Continue reading the documentation. That object you are getting back has attributes from which you get both (a) get its children and (b) get the data.